# Accesing to a drawable through its name in Android

Tags: android, drawable

I'm developing an app thant handles a SQLite database. I just get some information from it and show it in a list of CardViews. Each CardView basically displays the name, the age and a picture of a person.

Everything is working fine, but now that I have implemented the database, I have some doubts about it.

I just need to **access to the drawables through the name of the files**. So far I've been working manually with the R.drawable id, so I could check if it was working. Just like this:

> Person p1 = new Person(name, age, R.drawable.person1);

And then I just add that Person to a List of Persons, to then pass this List as a parameter to the Adapter.

Basicaly, the name of the person and the name of the image is exactly the same. So, now that I get all of the persons from the database (in a list), I'd like to get the drawable from the file name, but I only now how to get it through the R.drawable.id of the picture.

I'd like to change the R.drawable attribute from an `int` to a `String`, so I can access the way I want.

My question is, is there anyway to do something like `getDrawable("name_of_the_file.png");` or anything similar? Or is there any way to get the R.drawable.id through the name of the file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there anyway to do something like getDrawable("name_of_the_file.png"); or anything similar?

No.

> Or is there any way to get the R.drawable.id through the name of the file?

[Call `getIdentifier()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) on a `Resources` object to retrieve the numeric `R` value given the package, resource type (e.g., `"drawable"`), and resource name (e.g., `"example"`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just what I was looking for.