# How to get resource variable from a string for bitmapFactory

Tags: android, string, bitmap, android-resources, bitmapfactory

I am trying to load a resource into bitmap via position of image in gallery.I am getting the correct text set on "drawableId" but when it is set to string and reference in Bitmap line of code it comes up with an error with "a" in this line of code `Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), a)`.

If I substitute `a` with `R.drawable.pg1` it works fine.

```
String a = drawableId.getText().toString();           
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), a);
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            postPicture();
        }

        public boolean postPicture() {
            String a = drawableId.getText().toString();

            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), (a));
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image File"));
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to check the docs. the second param required is a int which is resource id required not a string. so this **R.drawable.pg1** should work fine

Comment: [decodeResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)) takes an int as the second parameter, not a string. You should really read your error message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38447612/115145

Comment: Thanks so far for the help. However I'm trying the switch between multiple images in an imageSwitcher R.drawable.pg1, R.drawable.pg2, etc. And the string "a" =R.drawable.pg*. But it sets and error. Is there different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For different way try this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(a, "id", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b); 
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
```